# Resizing HTML Iframe using a src I can't control

Tags: javascript, html, api, iframe

I'm developing an application that is feed a URL containing a session token from an API. This URL will grant the user of the application the ability to view search results from 3rd party databases via the API.

The issue that I'm facing is that when presenting the results (The URL) in an iframe it looks very ugly due to the iframe's scroll bar. I've poked about got the usual Google results, but I'm finding I'm quite stumped as to how to expand the iframe's height to match the incoming content.

I found an example of exactly what I'd like to happen but on trying to replicate the code I'm having no luck.

[The link in question](http://frank.bridgewater.edu/test/iframeResize/) ... As you can see the page loads an iframe into a basic HTML table and expands to accommodate the size of the content in the iframe.

Here's the source code for the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" border=1>
    <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Navigation</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <iframe onload="resize(this)" src="/test/phpinfo.php">
        </iframe>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>footer</td></tr>
</table>    
<script>
function resize(elem){
    var outer=elem;
    var inner=elem.contentDocument.documentElement; 
    outer.style.border="0";
    outer.style.overflow="hidden";
    outer.style.height=Number(inner.scrollHeight+10)+"px";
    outer.style.width=Number(inner.scrollWidth+10)+"px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing special right? But copypasta of the code (obviously changing the src) does nothing. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here, this should be 2 second job, but it's not working for me. This is all client side stuff, right? No voodoo magic happening on the server.

So ladies and gentlemen, what am I doing wrong, or how can I better do this? Please bear in mind that I have no ability to effect the HTML in the iframe as it is served up via an API and I can't touch it.

Thank you

**EDIT :** This is the reason it won't work [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only access the iframe `contentDocument` with javascript when iframe origin and the iframe src origin equal and matches each other.

otherwise the browser dont allow you to access the inner `contentDocument`

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.de" from accessing 
a frame with origin "http://otherorigin.example.de". Protocols, 
domains, and ports must match.
```

your posted example page origin

```
http://frank.bridgewater.edu/test/iframeResize/
```

and iframe src origin

```
http://frank.bridgewater.edu/test/phpinfo.php
```

matches (equal origins). so here it is working and the script can access the iframe `contentDocument`

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. It is disappointing that I can't do what I'm wanting to do gracefully.

Comment: my pleasure! otherwise you can create a script on your host (same origin) that make the request on a third party destintation and display this the user and your iframe pointed at this script - if it helps

Comment: Hmmm, that would work using php cURL. But there's a further issue, that the data from the API is loaded via AJAX once the connection is made. I would assume that all I'd get in return would be the HTML for a loading bar.

In order for this to work, I'd need to somehow get cURL to go to the URL wait for about 10 seconds and then return with the HTML it can see at that point.

I'll have to see if that is possible.